# Calling a function from one Windows Form to another

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++-cli

As simple as the title. I'm trying to call a function from one Windows Form to another. Form1 is my main form and SpecificsDialogBox is the subform.

As for the SpecificsDialogBox I have this as a constructor:

```
private: System::Windows::Forms::Form^ mainForm; //User generated code.
public:
    SpecificsDialogBox(System::Windows::Forms::Form^ frm)
    {
        mainForm = frm; //User generated code.
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
    }
```

So when I press the button this is what I currently have. dialogBoxInput() is the function I'm trying to call in the main form.

```
    private: System::Void okBtn_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
    {
        mainForm->dialogBoxInput(txtBox->Text);
        txtBox->Text = "";
        this->Hide();
    }
```

In the main form this is the function:

```
    public: void dialogBoxInput(String^ input)
    {
        //Code here
    }
```

How I'm opening the dialog box in the first place:

```
    private: System::Void specificsBtn_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
    {
        Form^ dialogBox = gcnew SpecificsDialogBox(this);
        dialogBox->Show();
    }
```

The error I'm getting is "dialogBoxInput is not a member of the System::Windows::Forms::Form" which I can guess is how I'm storing the Form1 in the dialog box header, but I'm not entirely sure how to get through this. Any help is appreciated.

***EDIT:***

After doing further research I learned about forward declarations. So instead of calling the Form1 class into SpecificsDialogBox I now have just this in my SpecificsDialogBox class:

```
public ref class SpecificsDialogBox : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
class Form1; //User generated code.
public:
    SpecificsDialogBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
    }

...

private: System::Void okBtn_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
    {
        Form1* mainForm;
        mainForm->dialogBoxInput(txtBox->Text);
        txtBox->Text = "";
        this->Hide();
    }
};
```

However I still get a compilation error "use of undefined type 'SpecificsDialogBox::Form1' see declaration of 'SpecificsDialogBox::Form1'". Which the debugger points me to both the calling of the function and where I defined `class Form1;`

Comment: Is this C++/CLI? I see no VB.NET here.

Comment: You need to either declare the mainForm variable in your SpecificDialogBox form as the specific type of the main form or cast to that type in order to call dialogBoxInput function

Comment: @o_weisman I did some more research into that and found out about forward declarations. Solved some problems, but still one left. In SpecificsDialogBox I have `class Form1;` and in okBtn_Click function I have `Form1* mainForm; &mainForm->dialogBoxInput(txtBox->Txt);` yet it's saying Form1 is an undefined type which may be a problem with my declaration. Some help?

Comment: This is the hard way to discover that C++ uses a single-pass compiler.  Fixing this requires splitting your declarations and implementations into separate files.  .h and .cpp files, every C++ programmer knows the drill.